# Connected Einstein manifolds with dimension $\geq 3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

I was able to compute the first part, with some computations I indeed got to:

$$\displaystyle{\sum_{i, k, h, j}} \delta_{ik}\delta_{hj}e_s(R_{hijk}) = n e_s(\lambda)$$

but for the other parts, I got all the way up to:

$$\displaystyle{\sum_{i, k, h, j}} \delta_{ik}\delta_{hj}e_j(R_{hiks}) = - \displaystyle{\sum_{j,h} \delta_{hj}e_j(\lambda \cdot \delta_{sh})}$$
$$\displaystyle{\sum_{i, k, h, j}}\delta_{ik}\delta_{hj} e_k (R_{hisj}) = - \displaystyle{\sum_{i,k} \delta_{ik} e_k(\lambda \cdot \delta_{is})}$$

and then got stuck. How are these both equal to $-e_s(\lambda)$? I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: It's always good to say where you got the exercise from (I guess it's Do Carmo's book in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did all the hard work. Note, for example, that
$$\sum_{j,h} \delta_{hj}\delta_{sh} e_j(\lambda) = \sum_j \delta_{sj}e_j(\lambda) = e_s(\lambda).$$

Comment: Of course! Damn I get stuck on the most trivial stuff ever. And then the rest follows from connectedness and since $n>=3$. Thanks!